# Valuerror in admin form

Tags: django, django-forms

Following is my model and form:

models.py

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='Employee Code')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Employee Name')

    def get_names(self):
        return Employee.objects.values_list('name', 'name')

class JobQueue(models.Model):
    emp_name = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_code = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
```

forms.py

```
class JobQueueForm(forms.ModelForm):

    emp = Employee()
    prod = Product()

    emp_name = forms.ChoiceField(choices = emp.get_names)
    product_code = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=prod.get_products)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        return super(JobQueueForm, self).save(commit = commit)

    class Meta:
        model = JobQueue
        fields = ('emp_name', 'product_code')
```

When I try to add new employee from JobQueue form, I get the following error:

ValueError at /admin/timesheet/jobqueue/add/
Cannot assign "'some_name'": "JobQueue.emp_name" must be a "Employee" instance.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You have a name clash, basically, which is a red herring for you when debugging this.

You have `emp_name` in your form which is a `ChoiceField` (string) but when you save the form to the database the backing model `JobQueue` is expecting `emp_name` to be an instance of an employee.

In your case you'd need to override the `save` method in your form, which you've shown intent on doing already, and fetch the employee there overriding `emp_name` and saving it.

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    self.emp_name = Employee.objects.get(name=self.cleaned_data['emp_name'])
    return super(JobQueueForm, self).save(commit=commit)
```